# Stuck with create batch transaction locally to use it as manual input in Transaction Builder UI

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

## Aim

Use a local script to batch transactions, after which the data field is logged and used as manual input in the Gnosis Transaction Builder UI custom data field

## Context

- A list of roughly 50+ address should receive non-transferrable ERC20 tokens in varying amounts.
- The token contract uses a proxy pattern
- The owner of the token contract is the multi-sig. The token have to be "air-minted" to the addresses and the mint function is restricted to only the owner.
- I myself are not an owner or delegate of the given multi-sig so I cant propose a tx through a script, signing it locally
- The chain I'm using is Celo

## Approach I'm taking

Create the transaction local with a script, copy pasting the data string in the custom data field in the Transaction Builder UI.

### What works

Using the [multi-sent Gnosis package](https://github.com/gnosis/ethers-multisend/tree/main), I am able to get it to work with a single transaction. After logging the data string, I just input it into the Transaction Builder UI with the correct contract address and are able to create a transaction.
This is the code I'm using

```
  // Encode transactions
  const tx1: MetaTransaction = encodeSingle({
    type: TransactionType.callContract,
    to: '0x59578a7381a77770B4615...',
    abi: deployer.token.interface.format(FormatTypes.json) as string,
    value: '',
    functionSignature: 'mint(address,uint256)',
    inputValues: {
      account: '0x62266a37cb6C4a06c10eD6...', // Address that receives the tokens
      amount: parseEther('2').toString(), // Amount of tokens
    },
    id: '',
  });
  console.log(tx1.data);
```

### What doesn't work

I tried following the same approach as above, using the MetaTransaction from the output of the `encodeSingle` function as input for the `encodeMulti` function. However when outputting the data field and pasting it into the custom data field, I get presetet with the error 'GS013', which basically tells me that something has gone wrong in the way I want to call the contract. I don't really have any other error log.
The code I used to generate the multi-send data field looks like this

```
  const finalTx = encodeMulti(
    [
      {
        to: '0x59578a7381a77770B461...',
        value: parseEther('1').toString(), // This amount is not calculated but taken from the example tests: https://github.com/gnosis/ethers-multisend/blob/main/test/encodeMulti.spec.ts#L41
        data: '0x40c10f1900000000000000000000000062266a37cb6c4a06c...69c7efcb70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001bc16d674ec80000', // Output of tx1.data
      },
      {
        to: '0x59578a7381a77770B46153A...',
        value: parseEther('1').toString(),
        data: '0x40c10f19000000000000000000000000fda58254cbf6fa8ec...4cf5b7ebee35e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001bc16d674ec80000', // Output of tx2.data
      },
    ],
    '0xA1dabEF33b3B82c7814B6D82A79e50F4AC44102B' // multisent contract Celo https://explorer.celo.org/mainnet/address/0xA1dabEF33b3B82c7814B6D82A79e50F4AC44102B/contracts#address-tabs
  );

  console.log(finalTx.data);
```

When batching a tx through the Gnosis Transaction Builder, it is sent to the multi-sent contract (see address in code snippet) for execution. When batching the tx, the `to` value is defined as the receiver contract so I've used the multi-send contract as receiver address as well, using the custom data field to past the output of my script but same error

Any help is appreciated!